# send table contents in a form on submit through request.POST in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have an form like below

```
   <form method="post" action={{ url/to/page }}>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <table>
       <tr>
           <td name="test">2</td>
           <td name="test1">3</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
```

On pressing submit, request.POST dictionary received in views.py do not have the td elements? Can someone please help?

If i have an input readonly element inside td blocks, i can getting the data in request.POST dictionary

But I want to know if there is a way to get td elements innerHTML parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td` is not part of the form, it's for the styling. When submitting a form the fields in it will be submitted, nothing else. You can use hidden inputs if you want `<input type="hidden" name="test" value="2">` will not be visible but submitted.

[Try reading a bit about how forms works in HTML.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

If you really want it in this way you can it to work with JavaScript instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i generate table on the fly through java script. 

I generally use hidden inputs for disabled fields. As in this case, i am generating dynamically, i do not want add hidden inputs.

What i did was placed a readonly input inside td, styled (css) to fit into the table styling.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?